# Multiple prefixed routes and DRY principle

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I use CakePHP 2.2.7

In my app I have a public area and admin area. 
I use prefixed routes so for admin actions I use 
`admin_index()` etc.

Now I need to add additional admin area for managers. This manager area will be different in some cases against the admin area.
Different layout, not all actions allowed.

My question is:
Should I simply duplicate actions which already implemented for admin area (and add another prefix, for example `manager_index()` ) or there is a more simple and DRY solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for example

```
public function manager_edit($fooId = null) {
    $this->admin_edit($fooId);
}
```

But if you did a good job most of your code should be already in the model and your code look like this (just a basic example);

```
public function manager_edit($fooId = null) {
    if ($this->Foo->edit($fooId, $this->request->params, $this->Auth->user('id')) { /*....*/ }
}
```